# Docker doesn't release / display space after running system prune and informing about reclaiming 16 gb on windows 10 home edition

Tags: docker

so I'm really new to docker, and my friend told me that docker system prune run from the elevated cmd prompt suppose to clean pretty much everything, after running it however the message notifying about "reclaiming 16.24 gb" was displayed but my file explorer doesn't show any changes to disk c, restart of docker or host machine didn't help, pruning volumes yield same results. How do I make him release the space or display it correctly (as I don't really know what the case is) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the internals of Docker for Windows, but fairly recently it worked by having a small virtual machine with a virtual disk image. The reclaimed disk space is inside that virtual disk image, but the "file" for that image will still remain the same size on your physical disk. If you want to reclaim the physical disk space, there should be a "Reset Docker" button somewhere in the Docker for Windows control panel, which will essentially delete that disk image and create a new, empty one.

Comment: thanks a ton that did stop this greedy bastard from devouring my computer, however is there a solution which wouldn't remove everything? i currently have somewhat slow connection and resetting means making the image again and again, so downloading everything up.

Comment: I don't know of any turn-key solution for something like that, but assuming you have another disk with space, you could use `docker save` to make backups of images. Then, after resetting the virtual disk, use `docker load` to restore the backups to the new disk, and `docker tag` to re-assign any tags, instead of re-downloading them.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the Docker data folder is still taking up space but there is no files inside, but running the following releases the storage space.

In PowerShell:

**wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data**